# Getting an Image from Telerik Sitefinity Modules

Tags: c#, telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I'm using Telerik Sitefinity 5.1. I've build a module that has 3 fields {title, url, image} title and url -> string field
image -> 'image selector'

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        var myCollection = GetDataItems();

        RadRotator1.DataSource = myCollection;
        RadRotator1.DataBind();
    }

    public IQueryable<DynamicContent> GetDataItems()
    {
        DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
        Type brandLogosType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.BrandLogos.BrandLogos");         
        var myCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(brandLogosType).Where(i => i.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible == true);

        return myCollection;
    }
```

asp.x

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" runat="server" RotatorType="AutomaticAdvance"
BorderWidth="4px" Width="100px" Height="100px" ScrollDirection="Down">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" />
    <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
    <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UrlWithExtension") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Getting `title` and `url` field with `Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'` But don't know how to get image like this. Can somebody show me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Image field stores a reference to a Sitefinity image using a ContentLink, this ContentLink is what is actually stored in the property.

You can expand the content link to get the image with a helper method, as described here: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/josh-morales-blog/2012/01/19/retrieving_data_from_dynamic_modules_using_the_module_builder_api

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had solved that issue via creating a function in code behind file at our custom control, and called that method inside control.ascx file where i have added a repeater &  asp.net image control field to show the image here is the solution with example in my site

[Get Images in custom control from Custom module image asset field](http://ashfaqahmed.net/sitefinity-custom-module-loading-images/)